# What alternatives do I have to cap/plug the kitchen spray nozzle

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, sink

I have a seasonal camp that is winterized each year.  The kitchen faucet spray nozzle must have suffered from some ice damage and leaks constantly.

The feed line to it comes from the mixed section of the faucet and there is no way to disconnect it.

I would like to avoid buying a whole new faucet set and I do not use the spray nozzle.

Can I just cut it and cap it or is there another way to correct this problem?  (the water leaks all the time and if I don't keep the sprayer in the basin it leaks into the cabinet)

I don't want to replace the hose/sprayer - since I also want to use the hole in the sink back for something else.  I don't use the sprayer.

I suppose the answers depend on the model of faucet - in this case it is a MOEN - and it does not look like the host it detatchable.

Answer (score 4):

Since you did not provide the model of the faucet, here is a [YouTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-i0CMPcs0B4) that shows how to cap a typical sprayer. In this situation, you'll likely need a 1/4" brass cap, some [PTFE tape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_seal_tape), and an adjustable wrench.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion(s) - I think that is what I am looking for.  Unfortunately I don't have the model number.  It is a seasonal camp in VT and I live down in NY.  Did not get the model number when I was up last.  I also did not see a connector for the hose - that is my problem.  Perhaps I missed it.  I might have to cut the host and plug it.

Comment: Tim, have you tired getting the model number by using Moen's website? You answer a series of questions and they try to determine the model that you have. You might be able to get a shop drawing or a parts list. Here's the site: http://www.moen.com/replacement-parts

Answer (score 1):

Most [Moen](http://www.moen.com/consumer-support/warranty) products have a lifetime limited warranty. That's why I agree with their slogan (at least the second part): buy it for looks, buy it for life.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is no easy metal connector to unscrew the sprayer hose. If it's just the rubber/plastic hose that disappears to somewhere that's inaccessible , you could cut the hose & stick a barbed hose plug in it:

[image: hose plug]

& hold it on with a hose clamp:

[image: hose clamp]

Even just folding the hose & clamping/tying it that way might be enough to stop the water flow, like when a garden hose gets kinked

[image]